# VB.NET cmd.CommandText is not working properly with sql update

Tags: sql, vb.net

This is my subtract button, it will just subtract the qty in my database but the math logic is wrong, for example, If I said 12-2 it updates the qty to 6

```
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Close()

    End If
    con.Open()


    Try
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Close()

        End If

        con.Open()

        cmd = con.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text


        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tablekongbago SET qty = qty + 2 WHERE Id = 2"
        cmd.CommandType = "UPDATE tablekongbago SET qty = (qty - 2) WHERE Id = 2"
        cmd.CommandText = "update tablekongbago set qty = qty - " + Convert.ToInt32(qtybox1.Text) + "WHERE Id = 2"
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tablekongbago SET qty = qty - 2 WHERE Id = " & 2 & ""
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tablekongbago SET qty = qty - " + Convert.ToInt32(2) + " WHERE Id = 2"
```

Any of this 5 "cmd.CommandText is not working properly, it add and subtracts but the qty it updates to the database is wrong, it produces a wrong output, e.g (12 - 2 = 6)

```
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        While dr.Read

            qty = dr.GetInt32(3).ToString()




        End While

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    MessageBox.Show("Subtracted Successfully")
```

Comment: What is your sql backend (MySQL, Oracle, Sql Server, etc.) ?  Note that the output of a SQL `UPDATE` DML statement is the number of records updated, not your _quantity_.

Comment: I'm using MySQL mdf database in visual studio, using cmd.CommandText = "", I want to change the qty, "UPDATE table SET qty = 12 WHERE Id = 2" works but "UPDATE table SET qty = qty -2 WHERE Id =2" doesn't, My qty is 12 but Whenever I use "UPDATE table SET qty = qty -2 WHERE Id =2" the qty changes to 6.

Comment: In case of, can you check if there is any triggers (specially an `UPDATE` one) on `table` ?

Comment: *"I'm using MySQL mdf database"*. Huh? No you're not. If you're using an MDF data file then that's SQL Server, not MySQL. If the `SqlClient` provider works at all then you must be using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first call `ExecuteNonQuery` on the command, which will subtract 2 from the current value. You next create a data adapter with the same command in its `SelectCommand` and then call `Fill`, which will execute the same command again and subtract another 2. Finally, you call `ExecuteReader` on the same command again, which will subtract another 2. Tell me, what's (12 - 2 - 2 - 2)? The command is working exactly as it should. You're just executing two extra times for no reason.

Why would you be using a data adapter and a data reader in that situation at all? There is no `SELECT` statement anywhere and both `Fill` and `ExecuteReader` are intended for executing queries, i.e. `SELECT` statements.

Comment: Thank you so much, now it works correctly, I just commented it out, I don't really understand that part of code that you said, I just copied that code from my datagridview function